# Port in use but not visible in TcpView or netstat

Tags: networking, windows-10, port, windows-10-v1903

I've been having issues where my IIS Express site doesn't start in Visual Studio 2019, because the system says port is in use.  However, the port does not show when I run TCPView or Netstat.  Sometimes rebooting will free it up, sometimes it does not.  How can I find what is using the port?  This is on Windows 10 Pro 1903 with all required updates.

Comment: Take a look at some of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use) question.